# What difference does it make or what difference do it make?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Which one of the following questions is correct? Or what are the different contexts when they are used if both are correct?

> What difference does it make?

Or

> What difference do it make?

Comment: Singular: *What difference **does he** make?* Plural: *What difference **do they** make?*

Comment: Do you know how to choose a verb tense? The same rules apply

Answer (score 0):

Based on FumbleFinger's now deleted comment-answer:

***it*** is singular, so the verb form must be ***does***. Idiomatically, when we're asking the specific question as presented here (with ...does ***it*** make?), we'd always use the singular anyway. They might be "syntactically valid", but native speakers would rarely if ever ask What ***differences are made by it***? or What ***differences does it*** make?